# I can't write some characters in my java file (encoding problems)

Tags: java, encoding, char

I can't write some characters in my file , any string which has caracter like 'é' 'à' etc.. is written but the mentioned characters are changed into some special characters '@'..., can anyone tell me what's the problem with my code please ?
I also want to initially create my file in UTF-16 little endian without bom only little endian, is that the way to do it ?

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-16LE");
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
BufferedReader lire = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
do {
    String line = lire.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    //<a href="Substance/acide_folinique-3875.htm">acide folinique</a>

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"Substance/.+>(.+)</a>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        byte ptext[] = m.group(1)
                        .getBytes("UTF-16LE");
        String line2 = new String(ptext, "UTF-16LE");
        String line3 = line2.toLowerCase();


        writer.write(line3 + ",.N+subst");
        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    } else {
        p = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"Medicament/.+>(.+)\\s.+</a>");
        m = p.matcher(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            byte ptext[] = m.group(1)
                            .getBytes("UTF-16LE");
            String line2 = new String(ptext, "UTF-16LE");
            String line3 = line2.toLowerCase();


            writer.write(line3 + ",.N+medic");
            writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

    }


} while (true);

writer.close();
```

Comment: Where are those characters with the diacritical marks in your code? And UTF-16 is not the best choice for writing text files - why?

Comment: for example : the original: abiratérone,.N+subst
 becomes : abiratã©rone,.N+subst

Comment: It is possible that the way you display the text file onto which "abiratérone" has been written is not capable of displaying UTF-? encoded texts correctly - which will make you think the file contains gibberisch. You need a hexadecimal dump of the file to make sure that the data has been written correctly, or a system where text files are assumed to be in the encoding you used to write the text file. UTF-16*E is not a good choice. Why?

Comment: How is the file that you are reading encoded? You are using the default character encoding of the jvm (likely default of the host os) to read the file. If that does not match the actual file, then that is likely where the diacritic characters are being lost.

Comment: Why are you creating the `byte[]` from the regex match only to convert back to a `String`? That is completely wasted work.

Answer (score 1):

What is the encoding of your input file? If it's not the default encoding of the machine on which your program happens to run, the data will be corrupted as it's read. In the example below, I assume the input is UTF-16LE; if that's wrong, you'd need to change the `Charset` passed to the `newBufferedReader()` call.

```
try (BufferedReader lines = Files.newBufferedReader(src, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
     Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dst, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)) {
  Pattern substance = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"Substance/.+>(.+)</a>");
  Pattern medic = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"Medicament/.+>(.+)\\s.+</a>");
  String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
  while (true) {
    String line = lines.readLine();
    if (line == null)
      break;
    Matcher m = substance.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
      String ptext = m.group(1).toLowerCase();
      writer.write(ptext);
      writer.write(",.N+subst");
      writer.write(sep);
    } else {
      m = medic.matcher(line);
      if (m.find()) {
        String ptext = m.group(1).toLowerCase();
        writer.write(ptext + ",.N+medic");
        writer.write(sep);
      }
    }
  }
}
```